# Use join to aggregate data from various normalized tables

Tags: mysql-5.5, join, select

I have a database as follows:

```
tbl_clients (Primary Key: client_id, Foreign Keys:place_id,district_id,zone_id,country_id)
tbl_places (Primary Key: place_id)
tbl_districts (Primary key: district_id)
tbl_zones (Primary Key: zone_id)
tbl_country (Primary key: country_id)
tbl_branches (primary key: branch_id, Foreign Key: client_id)
```

My client asked me to provide all the data in a csv file. The requirement is:

If a client has branches, the branches details also should show.(from tbl_branch)
If a client does not have branches,only its details should show.

I have achieved the second condition using the following:

```
select distinct     
    a.name  as Client_Name,
    a.pobox_no  as Postal_Address,
    a.street  as Street_Address,
    d.place_name as Place,
    e.district_name as District,
    f.zone_name as Zone,
    g.country_name as Country,
    a.fax  as Fax,
    a.telephone  as Telephone,
    a.telephone2  as Telephone2,
    a.email  as Email,
    a.website  as website,
    a.published  as Published

from 
    db_name.tbl_client a
join 
    db_name.tbl_subcategory b on a.sub_cat_id = b.cat_id
join 
    db_name.tbl_category c on a.category_id = c.id
join
    db_name.tbl_place d on a.place_id = d.place_id
join
    db_name.tbl_districts e on a.district_id = e.district_id
join
    db_name.tbl_zones f on a.zone_id = f.zone_id
join
    db_name.tbl_country g on a.country_id = g.country_id

where 
    a.published = 1
```

How can I achieve the first condition?

Comment: Use `left join branches on ...`

Comment: And skip the `distinct`, it's redundant I think. And why are you joining the category tables if you don't have any column from them in the select list?

Comment: Sorry I missed the categories column!

Comment: I tried using right join.But the problem is, the branches tables also have district_id,place_id and zone_id as foreign key. I am getting ids there while I need the respective names (District Zone and Place) same as in the above query

Comment: Use `left join`, not `right join`. First (left) join branches, then (left) join to all the tables, related to branches.